# Patching AutoComplete In React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui, formik

I have a problem patching the values of AutoComplete in my React App. The value that i passed is only the `id` as you can see `function App({ member_status = 1 })` in my codesandbox. The Autocomplete needs the whole object to patch its values. How would i patch it?

Pls see my codesandbox below

[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/edit-mode-autocomplete-formik-material-ui-react-forked-rpbwn?file=/src/index.js:481-504)

**CODE**

```
function App({ member_status = 1 }) 

initialValues={{
   member_status: member_status
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the initial value as an object from the selection options

```
initialValues={{
  member_status: memberStatuses.find((x) => x.id === member_status)
}}
```

## [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/edit-mode-autocomplete-formik-material-ui-react-forked-zkwwi)